# How to create an ISO disk image of an NVMe SSD?

Tags: linux, dd, disk-image

I want to create a disk image of my solid-state drive using the `dd` (disk dump) command. There are multiple partitions on the SSD. Is it possible to make a complete image of the drive including all partitions?

This is an example of how it works with an HDD:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/mnt/sdb/disk.img conv=sync,noerror bs=64K
```

However, I'm unsure because in `/dev/` the paths to my NVMe SSD look different. There are  these variants: 
 `/dev/nvme0` 
 `/dev/nvme0n1` 
 `/dev/nvme0n1p1` 
 `/dev/nvme0n1p2` 
 `/dev/nvme0n1p3` 
 `/dev/nvme0n1p4`

Which path do I have to set as the input file `if=` ? Why? `nvme0n1p1` to `nvme0n1p4` are the four partitions. As I said before, I don't want to create an image of a single partition only. What is the difference between `nvme0` and `nvme0n1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want do make image of the entire disk, use `/dev/nvme0n1`, this is the NVMe drive block device (it's actually a "[namespace](https://nvmexpress.org/resources/nvm-express-technology-features/nvme-namespaces/)", you can in theory have multiple namespaces on an NVMe drive, it's like a "partition on a hardware level", but most "consumer" NVMes come with only one namespace).

`/dev/nvme0` is controller, a character device  used for control/management of the NVMe device (like adding new namespaces, changing block size etc.).You can use *nvme-cli* tools for NVMe management, for example to get SMART data or temperature using the `nvme0` device:

```
sudo nvme smart-log /dev/nvme0
Smart Log for NVME device:nvme0 namespace-id:ffffffff
critical_warning                        : 0
temperature                             : 38 C
available_spare                         : 100%
...
```

(But I generally don't recommend playing with the tool, you can remove everything from the drive by accident very easily.)

ArchWiki has a [great article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive/NVMe) about NVMes if you're interested in more details, but everything you need to know is:

- ignore `nvme0`, you'll probably never use it
- `nvme0n1` is the drive (= `sda`)
- `nvme0n1pX` are partitions on `nvme0n1`, the only difference is instead of `sda + number` you have `nvme0n1 + p + number` where `p` means "partition" and is added only because `nvme0n1` ends with a digit (that isn't NVMe-specific)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! I've quickly looked up character and block devices: So the difference is that with a block device it is only possible to communicate by sending entire **blocks** of data (as it is usually the case with hard drives) and with a character devices it is possible to communicate by sending single **characters** (bytes).

So as the `nvme0` device is only there for control/managemant, am I right to asume that it does not actually send any data that is stored on the SSD but only sends data to communicate for control/management purposes?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I updated my answer in the meantime to make it little more clear (I hope).

Comment: Yes, thanks for the extra details, that's helpful as well!

Comment: Is there a reason why the major number `239` of `nvme0` is exactly the size of my SSD? (At least if you believe the size of `238.5G` that `lsblk` gives. Windows Disk Management gives a more precise value of `238.46 GB` which had to be rounded down to 238 instead of 239.)

Comment: No, major number has nothing to do with size. [Major numbers from 234 to 254](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt) are used for character devices and the major number is assigned "randomly" (actually depends on which device takes the number first, starting from 254; I also have 239 on my desktop but 240 on laptop), you can check `/proc/devices` for list of devices (types) and assigned majors.

Comment: Okey, thank you for the info. In the beginning I didn't know about major and minor numbers and why `ls -l` looks different in `/dev/`. I was really confused because the numbers all looked like storage sizes (around 250, which is roughly the size of my SSD) and I didn't understand how the numbers come about. But that's clear to me now :)

Comment: Running `dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of=/media/mint/My\ Passport/Images/nvme01n1.img` I created an image of my NVMe SSD. I assume that creating an disk image means that the image file contains the exact same bits as the original SSD does. Is this true? When I open the image file in 7-Zip File Manager, I can see another four .img files: `0.Basic data partition.img` `1.EFI system partition.img`
 `2.Microsoft reserved partition.img` `3.Basic data partition.img`. Does this mean that partitions on my SSD are actually stored in a format that is the same as an .img file? Or did `dd` add these .img files?